# Работа с массивом

Tags: php

Как в массиве найти одинаковые элементы ?

Answer (score 1):

Используем функции count и array_unique

```
$r = (count($array) == count(array_unique($array)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Пользоваться поисковиком не модно видимо сейчас. `print_r(array_count_values($array));`
Пробуйте, удачи.

Answer (score 0):

```
array_diff_key($array, array_unique($array))
```